# Change a ListView's displayed columns based on a DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have a wpf control that can be used in two different windows. The control contains a ListView, which is fed by an ObservableCollection of the same class, regardless of which window is hosting the control.

In one window I want to show a certain set of columns, and in the other window a different set of columns.

I have included a trivial example of what I am trying to accomplish. For the purposes of this example, the xml is contained in a window rather than a UserControl.

Here is the xaml that defines the window and its two ListViews:

```
<Window x:Class="ListTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="listOne"  TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <ListView Margin="10,30,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Food" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Food}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="listTwo"  TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <ListView Margin="10,30,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Number" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Number}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="State" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding State}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="Complex" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              IsChecked="{Binding IsComplex}"/>
    <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvUsers" Template="{StaticResource listTwo}" />
</Grid>
```

This is my trivial viewmodel, and the record class:

```
    public class MyRecord
{
    public MyRecord(string firstName, string food, int number, string state)
    {
        Name = firstName;
        Food = food;
        Number = number;
        State = state;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Food { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<MyRecord> _recordList;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _recordList = new List<MyRecord>();
        _recordList = new List<MyRecord>();
        _recordList.Add(new MyRecord("Lee", "pizza", 10, "ID"));
        _recordList.Add(new MyRecord("Gary", "burger", 20, "UT"));

        MyList = new ObservableCollection<MyRecord>(_recordList);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyRecord> _myList;
    public ObservableCollection<MyRecord> MyList
    {
        get { return _myList; }
        set
        {
            if (_myList != value)
            {
                _myList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => MyList);
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _isComplex = true;
    public bool IsComplex
    {
        get { return _isComplex; }
        set
        {
            if (_isComplex != value)
            {
                _isComplex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => IsComplex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The next-to-last line of the xaml has a hard-coded Template assignment:

```
        <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvUsers" Template="{StaticResource listTwo}" />
```

Changing that back and forth in the xaml results in the program displaying one ListView layout or the other without error.

I want to be able to set a property in the ViewModel that will control which layout is used - in this trivial case, I have a checkbox that should control the selected ListView.

I've tried triggers, which seems to be the simplest approach, but haven't found anything that makes the compiler happy.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

**Update:**
Ed Plunkett's response showed me that I was making my question too hard. I didn't want to replace the whole ListView, just control what columns were displayed within it. Extracting a bit of his code results in exactly the behavior I wanted originally without going into the code-behind and replacing the entire ListView. The displayed columns in my sample now switch to the correct "view" when I toggle the checkbox. The code-behind is untouched, and the viewmodel remains the same. Thanks Ed! I've accepted his answer because it showed me the subset of code I needed, and I've changed the Title to reflect what the real question was.

This is the complete revised xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="AAWorkTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="Complex" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              IsChecked="{Binding IsComplex}"/>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" Margin="10,30,10,30" Name="lvUsers">
        <ListView.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ListView">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsComplex}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="View">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Food" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Food}" />
                                </GridView>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsComplex}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="View">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Number" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Number}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="State" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding State}" />
                                </GridView>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Style>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set properties on a control by replacing the template with one that creates a new, nested instance of the control with different properties. In WPF, a ControlTemplate determines how a control is displayed, it doesn't create the control. Instead, you set properties with a style that sets the properties. If it *were* a good idea to change the ListView's template, this is how you would do that.

Here's how you can do this (I don't recommend naming it UserControl1, of course):

UserControl1.xaml.cs

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(UserControl1),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ViewPurpose ViewPurpose
    {
        get { return (ViewPurpose)GetValue(ViewPurposeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ViewPurposeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewPurposeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ViewPurpose), typeof(ViewPurpose), typeof(UserControl1),
            new PropertyMetadata(ViewPurpose.None));
}

public enum ViewPurpose
{
    None,
    FoodPreference,
    ContactInfo,
    FredBarneyWilma
}
```

UserControl1.xaml

```xml
<UserControl 
    x:Class="WpfApp3.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
            >
            <ListView.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ListView">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger 
                            Binding="{Binding ViewPurpose, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                            Value="FoodPreference"
                            >
                            <Setter Property="View">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <GridView>
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="Food" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Food}" />
                                    </GridView>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger 
                            Binding="{Binding ViewPurpose, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                            Value="ContactInfo"
                            >
                            <Setter Property="View">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <GridView>
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="Number" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Number}" />
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="State" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding State}" />
                                    </GridView>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Style>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Usage example:

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <local:UserControl1 
        ViewPurpose="FoodPreference"
        ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollectionOfWhatever}" 
        />
    <local:UserControl1 
        ViewPurpose="ContactInfo"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DifferentCollectionOfWhatever}" 
        />
</StackPanel>
```

The enum is one option for specifying a set of columns. You could also give it a collection of column name, or a single string delimited by some special character ("Name|Food|Gas|Lodging") that would be split, and then do something in the UserControl to create the collection of columns based on that.

But if you have two or three predefined collections of columns, with custom widths and so on, this is quick and simple and does the job. You don't need to get too clever with this one.